# Getting started with a website

Tags: html, web-development

So I know `HTML`, `CSS`, `Javascript`, `jQuery`, `PHP`. But I'm not sure how to put it all together to begin making an actual website. I'm not looking at something too big here since I'm just a beginner, but I need to start somewhere.

More specific stuff:

1. In what ways do I carry on my layout for which page in my website, without having to do it again for each page? Not only layout, but also stuff like menus which have to be on every page.
2. Should I use software like `Drupal`, or should I start off alone and start worrying about that later?
3. Is there a place where I can read about all this stuff?

Comment: I've read that, and didn't quite get an answer to my questions. Especially not the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quentin has touched on the answer, but I suspect you're looking for something a little meatier.  The technologies you've referenced are all very "front-end."  And they work great if you're building a small, static website.  But once the site begins to grow you start to need a little extra help to keep things manageable.  This help comes in the form of a "back-end."

The "back-end" today will usually be built using an existing framework.  The popular programming languages all have multiple frameworks available, but some examples to help you get an idea: Python has Django, Groovy has Grails, Ruby has Rails, and PHP has Drupal.

In large part these back-ends are built towards dynamic websites (that is, the content probably comes out of a database) rather than static websites (where the content may live entirely in HTML files).

Something advertising itself more as a CMS (Content Management System) is going to focus more on static-style sites, but doing the repetitive tasks for you.  The content may end up coming out of a database, but it probably doesn't have traditional, relational attributes that you'd normally find in data stored in a database.  By which I mean, the CMS may take paragraphs of text and store them in database for convenience rather than storing data like Users/Profiles/Forum Threads/Comments/etc.

Given what little information you've provided and based on the technologies you've listed a CMS is probably more what you're looking for than an entire back-end framework.

The CMS will help you with things like writing your CSS style once and then loading it on each page.  And creating a set of JavaScript files and loading them on each page also.

The end goal is to help you focus more on creating content and less on just getting the content displayed.

Hopefully that gives you enough information to guide your search and help yourself figure out what exactly will work for your needs.  Unfortunately I don't know of any good resources off-hand that will help you figure this stuff out.  I'd recommend doing some reading on Content Management Systems and maybe work through a few tutorials.  Essentially you'll be taking the skills you already have and figuring out how they fit inside a system someone else has built.

Answer (score 0):

1. CSS for presentation. A template language for duplicated content.
2. CMSes are tools and have their place. It is impossible to tell if your website is good place for one as we know nothing about it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the template language? What does that mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29